# SQL All Possible Round Robin Combinations between two Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, combinations, round-robin

given table:

```
create table Person( Name varchar(100) )
```

where Name is unique for all Persons

What SQL query can generate all possible n!/((n-2)!2!) round robin combinations?

It is assumed that the cardinality of Person is ALWAYS equal to 4

Example Person = {'Anna','Jerome','Patrick','Michael')

Output:

```
Anna, Jerome
Anna, Patrick
Anna, Michael
Jerome, Patrick
Jerome, Michael
Patrick, Michael
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here's my answer (I used oracle SQL):

```
select P1.NAME PERSON1, P2.NAME PERSON2
  from (select rownum RNUM, NAME
        from PERSON) P1,
       (select rownum RNUM, NAME
          from PERSON) P2
 where P1.RNUM < P2.RNUM
```

Comment: a simple join of two instances of the table where their names are not equals. However, this result to twice more rows that the correct solution, e.g. Anna,Michael and Michael,Anna (Incorrect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select P1.NAME PERSON1, P2.NAME PERSON2
  from (select rownum RNUM, NAME
        from PERSON) P1,
       (select rownum RNUM, NAME
          from PERSON) P2
 where P1.RNUM < P2.RNUM
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions for the problem

```
SELECT  t1.Name + ',' +  t2.Name AS NamesCombination
FROM Person t1
INNER JOIN Person t2
ON t1.Name < t2.Name
```

**OR (Oracle 11i R2+)**

```
WITH NamesCombination AS 
( 
    SELECT  1 AS Cntr
            ,Name 
            , CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(MAX))AS NamesCombinations
    FROM Person 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  
        nc.Cntr+1
        ,p.Name 
        ,nc.NamesCombinations + ',' +  CAST(p.Name AS VARCHAR(MAX))                      
    FROM Person AS p JOIN NamesCombination nc ON p.Name < nc.Name
    WHERE nc.Cntr < 2  
)
SELECT NamesCombinations
FROM NamesCombination
WHERE Cntr  = 2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is TSQL (Sql Server) syntax. I know that Oracle supports windowing functions, particularly row_number(), which is necessary for this solution.

It shouldn't be too hard to get this to work in Oracle with some trial and error

```
select p1.name, p2.name
from 
(
    select name,  row_number() over(order by name) as rownumber 
    from person
) p1
inner join
(
    select name, row_number() over(order by name) as rownumber
    from person
) p2
on p1.name <> p2.name
and p1.rownumber > p2.rownumber
order by 1
```

row_number assigns a row number to each row. You then need to join, as suggested before, with the additional join clause of p1.rownumber > p2.rownumber