# Implementing Double Round Robin Algorithm in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, algorithm, plsql

I'm new to `SQL` and I'm trying to make a table which stores the schedule of a football league. The table contains 4 columns (`matchID, home_team, away_team, match_date`). I have 8 different teams and each team should play against each of the other teams exactly twice. The tournament will last for 14 weeks(4 games per week). I searched and found out that the `double round robin algorithm` does the same thing but I'm not sure how to write it in PL/SQL and generate a table. Please help me.

Comment: It looks like there is a lot missing from this question. For example are there rules about how often a team is expected to play in a particular timeframe, are home and away games allowed to be sequential, what is the actual timeframe for all games to be played in (and lots of others I'm sure)

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372232/sql-all-possible-round-robin-combinations-between-two-tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/371ca/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE matches ( matchID, home_team, away_team, match_date ) AS
WITH rounds ( round, home, away, num_players ) AS (
  SELECT 1,
         LEVEL,
         num_players + 1 - LEVEL,
         num_players
  FROM   ( SELECT 8 AS num_players FROM DUAL )
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= num_players / 2
UNION ALL
  SELECT round + 1,
         CASE home
           WHEN 1 THEN 1
           WHEN 2 THEN num_players
           ELSE home - 1
         END,
         CASE away
           WHEN 2 THEN num_players
           ELSE away - 1
         END,
         num_players
  FROM   rounds
  WHERE  round < num_players - 1
)
SELECT ROWNUM,
       t.*
FROM   (
  SELECT home,
         away,
         DATE '2017-01-01' + ( round - 1 ) * 7 AS match_date
  FROM   rounds
  UNION ALL
  SELECT away,
         home,
         DATE '2017-01-01' + ( round + num_players - 2 ) * 7
  FROM   rounds
) t;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM matches
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/371ca/1/0)**:

```
| MATCHID | HOME_TEAM | AWAY_TEAM |           MATCH_DATE |
|---------|-----------|-----------|----------------------|
|       1 |         1 |         8 | 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z |
|       2 |         2 |         7 | 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z |
|       3 |         3 |         6 | 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z |
|       4 |         4 |         5 | 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z |
|       5 |         1 |         7 | 2017-01-08T00:00:00Z |
|       6 |         8 |         6 | 2017-01-08T00:00:00Z |
|       7 |         2 |         5 | 2017-01-08T00:00:00Z |
|       8 |         3 |         4 | 2017-01-08T00:00:00Z |
|       9 |         1 |         6 | 2017-01-15T00:00:00Z |
|      10 |         7 |         5 | 2017-01-15T00:00:00Z |
|      11 |         8 |         4 | 2017-01-15T00:00:00Z |
|      12 |         2 |         3 | 2017-01-15T00:00:00Z |
|      13 |         1 |         5 | 2017-01-22T00:00:00Z |
|      14 |         6 |         4 | 2017-01-22T00:00:00Z |
|      15 |         7 |         3 | 2017-01-22T00:00:00Z |
|      16 |         8 |         2 | 2017-01-22T00:00:00Z |
|      17 |         1 |         4 | 2017-01-29T00:00:00Z |
|      18 |         5 |         3 | 2017-01-29T00:00:00Z |
|      19 |         6 |         2 | 2017-01-29T00:00:00Z |
|      20 |         7 |         8 | 2017-01-29T00:00:00Z |
|      21 |         1 |         3 | 2017-02-05T00:00:00Z |
|      22 |         4 |         2 | 2017-02-05T00:00:00Z |
|      23 |         5 |         8 | 2017-02-05T00:00:00Z |
|      24 |         6 |         7 | 2017-02-05T00:00:00Z |
|      25 |         1 |         2 | 2017-02-12T00:00:00Z |
|      26 |         3 |         8 | 2017-02-12T00:00:00Z |
|      27 |         4 |         7 | 2017-02-12T00:00:00Z |
|      28 |         5 |         6 | 2017-02-12T00:00:00Z |
|      29 |         8 |         1 | 2017-02-19T00:00:00Z |
|      30 |         7 |         2 | 2017-02-19T00:00:00Z |
|      31 |         6 |         3 | 2017-02-19T00:00:00Z |
|      32 |         5 |         4 | 2017-02-19T00:00:00Z |
|      33 |         7 |         1 | 2017-02-26T00:00:00Z |
|      34 |         6 |         8 | 2017-02-26T00:00:00Z |
|      35 |         5 |         2 | 2017-02-26T00:00:00Z |
|      36 |         4 |         3 | 2017-02-26T00:00:00Z |
|      37 |         6 |         1 | 2017-03-05T00:00:00Z |
|      38 |         5 |         7 | 2017-03-05T00:00:00Z |
|      39 |         4 |         8 | 2017-03-05T00:00:00Z |
|      40 |         3 |         2 | 2017-03-05T00:00:00Z |
|      41 |         5 |         1 | 2017-03-12T00:00:00Z |
|      42 |         4 |         6 | 2017-03-12T00:00:00Z |
|      43 |         3 |         7 | 2017-03-12T00:00:00Z |
|      44 |         2 |         8 | 2017-03-12T00:00:00Z |
|      45 |         4 |         1 | 2017-03-19T00:00:00Z |
|      46 |         3 |         5 | 2017-03-19T00:00:00Z |
|      47 |         2 |         6 | 2017-03-19T00:00:00Z |
|      48 |         8 |         7 | 2017-03-19T00:00:00Z |
|      49 |         3 |         1 | 2017-03-26T00:00:00Z |
|      50 |         2 |         4 | 2017-03-26T00:00:00Z |
|      51 |         8 |         5 | 2017-03-26T00:00:00Z |
|      52 |         7 |         6 | 2017-03-26T00:00:00Z |
|      53 |         2 |         1 | 2017-04-02T00:00:00Z |
|      54 |         8 |         3 | 2017-04-02T00:00:00Z |
|      55 |         7 |         4 | 2017-04-02T00:00:00Z |
|      56 |         6 |         5 | 2017-04-02T00:00:00Z |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate records for your Table using this query. Note here that I have not enforced any `constraints` which is up to you and you **should**. You can write simple `CREATE TABLE (` syntax with all datatype and constraints and use this query to `insert` records.

**match_groups** generates the match combinations

**All_matches**  repeats the matches by swapping home team and away team.

```
CREATE TABLE MATCH_SCHEDULE AS WITH TEAMS (name) AS
  (SELECT 'TEAM1'
   FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 'TEAM2'
   FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 'TEAM3'
   FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 'TEAM4'
   FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 'TEAM5'
   FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 'TEAM6'
   FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 'TEAM7'
   FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 'TEAM8'
   FROM DUAL),
match_groups AS
  (SELECT t1.name home_team,
          t2.name away_team
   FROM
     (SELECT rownum RNUM,
                    NAME
      FROM TEAMS) t1
   JOIN
     (SELECT rownum RNUM,
                    NAME
      FROM TEAMS) t2 ON t1.RNUM < t2.RNUM),
All_matches AS
  (SELECT home_team,
          away_team
   FROM match_groups
   UNION ALL SELECT away_team home_team,
                    home_team away_team
   FROM match_groups)
SELECT ROWNUM matchID,
              home_team,
              away_team,
              SYSDATE + ROWNUM match_date
FROM All_matches;
```

This would create a table with following data.

TABLE **MATCH_SCHEDULE**

```
MATCHID HOME_TEAM   AWAY_TEAM     MATCH_DATE
1      TEAM1        TEAM2          09-OCT-17
2      TEAM1        TEAM3          10-OCT-17
3      TEAM1        TEAM4          11-OCT-17
4      TEAM1        TEAM5          12-OCT-17
5      TEAM1        TEAM6          13-OCT-17
6      TEAM1        TEAM7          14-OCT-17
...
...
54     TEAM7        TEAM6          01-DEC-17
55     TEAM8        TEAM6          02-DEC-17
56     TEAM8        TEAM7          03-DEC-17
```

Note that `MATCHID` has just numbers 1,2,3.... You can also make use of an Oracle `sequence` if you like or update it accordingly. Now, since you need to have 4 matches per week, you need to construct an adhoc `update` script based on your need with proper dates and run it.

Comment: Thanks for this. The table was successfully created. But I have one problem, according to the round robin algorithm, a team cant play its second match until all other teams have played their first match. That's why i wanted 4 matches per week so that all 8 teams would be done with their first match. Have a look at this http://tournamentscheduler.net/schedule/NDg2NDg0MzUzNg.

Comment: If it is a one time activity , you could generate the update scripts from excel for updating it to correct dates. For eg: `update table SET matchdate = <firstdate> where home_team = TEAM3 AND away_team = TEAM1 ` ,`update table SET matchdate = <seconddate> where home_team = TEAM5 AND away_team = TEAM7 ` .. and so on.

Comment: Yes that's easy but a time consuming way. Is there a way to create a procedure? And i guess it'd be easier if the match_date for all 4 games in a week are kept same so that all 4 matches are held on the same day. And hence every team will play a match after exactly one week.

Answer (score 0):

Try this procedure. The logic is based on round robin

Note that I used: week instead of date. Scheduling the matches for a specific date requires other information on how many per day, can you have a team playing more than once per week, etc.

The input to the procedure is a comma separated team list. If you input odd number, a "DUMMY" is created for round robin to work. This does not insert into a table but prompt you the schedule. You can replace the `DBMS_OUTPUT` statements with insert statements

```
    create or replace
    procedure test_schedule(p_teams in varchar2)
    is
      type t_teams is table of varchar2(15);
      cursor c_teams is
        select trim(regexp_substr(p_teams,'[^,]+', 1, level)) team
        from dual
        connect by regexp_substr(p_teams, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
      v_teams t_teams := t_teams();
      v_team_shift varchar2(60);
      v_weeks number;
      v_count number:=0;
      v_date date;
    begin
      for r_teams in c_teams loop
        v_count := v_count +  1;
        v_teams.extend();
        v_teams(v_count) := r_teams.team;
      end loop;
      if mod(v_count, 2) != 0 then
        v_count := v_count +  1;
        v_teams.extend();
        v_teams(v_count) := 'DUMMAY';
      end if;

      for i in 1..v_count loop
        dbms_output.put_line(v_teams(i));
      end loop;

      v_weeks := v_count - 1;
      dbms_output.put_line('Weeks: '|| v_weeks||' Count: '||v_count);

      for week in 1..v_weeks loop
        for i in 1..v_count/2 loop
          dbms_output.put_line(week||':    '||v_teams(i)||'   X    '||v_teams(v_count-i+1));
          dbms_output.put_line(week+v_weeks||':    '||v_teams(v_count-i+1)||'   X    '||v_teams(i));
        end loop;
        -- shift teams
        v_team_shift := v_teams(v_count);
        for i in 1..v_count-2 loop
          v_teams(v_count-i+1) := v_teams(v_count-i);
        end loop;
        v_teams(2) := v_team_shift;
      end loop;
    end;
    /
```

To test, I used:

```
begin test_schedule('TEAM A, TEAM B, TEAM C, TEAM D, TEAM E'); end;
/
```

The output:

```
    Week    Home        Away
    1:    TEAM A   X    DUMMAY
    6:    DUMMAY   X    TEAM A
    1:    TEAM B   X    TEAM E
    6:    TEAM E   X    TEAM B
    1:    TEAM C   X    TEAM D
    6:    TEAM D   X    TEAM C
    2:    TEAM A   X    TEAM E
    7:    TEAM E   X    TEAM A
    2:    DUMMAY   X    TEAM D
    7:    TEAM D   X    DUMMAY
    2:    TEAM B   X    TEAM C
    7:    TEAM C   X    TEAM B
    3:    TEAM A   X    TEAM D
    8:    TEAM D   X    TEAM A
    3:    TEAM E   X    TEAM C
    8:    TEAM C   X    TEAM E
    3:    DUMMAY   X    TEAM B
    8:    TEAM B   X    DUMMAY
    4:    TEAM A   X    TEAM C
    9:    TEAM C   X    TEAM A
    4:    TEAM D   X    TEAM B
    9:    TEAM B   X    TEAM D
    4:    TEAM E   X    DUMMAY
    9:    DUMMAY   X    TEAM E
    5:    TEAM A   X    TEAM B
    10:    TEAM B   X    TEAM A
    5:    TEAM C   X    DUMMAY
    10:    DUMMAY   X    TEAM C
    5:    TEAM D   X    TEAM E
    10:    TEAM E   X    TEAM D
```